# Configuring kong ingress for apache-nifi api on minikube

Tags: kubernetes, apache-nifi, kong-ingress

I am trying to configure kong ingress controller for apache nifi.

About nifi:

Apache nifi instance is running on minikube, and it exposes a rest api that can be accessed with URLs:

> http://ip:port/nifi-api/....

calls t /nifi-api work and results are returned as expected.

Service name for nifi instance in its yaml is 'nifi'.

For kong:

Installed kong on minikube, following [this](https://docs.konghq.com/kubernetes-ingress-controller/2.10.x/deployment/minikube/).
I can see kong resources created.

[image]

For creating ingress to put nifi api behind kong, following [this](https://docs.konghq.com/kubernetes-ingress-controller/2.10.x/guides/getting-started/).

My ingress yaml:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nifi-api-routing
  annotations:
    konghq.com/strip-path: 'true'
spec:
  ingressClassName: kong
  rules:
  - host: kong.example
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /nifi-api
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
        backend:
          service:
            name: nifi
            port:
              number: 30026
```

backend.service.name and backend.service.port are from service yaml for nifi. path is '/nifi-api' as nifi exposes its endpoints at it. host name 'kong.example' is same as one used in [link](https://docs.konghq.com/kubernetes-ingress-controller/2.10.x/guides/getting-started/).

My question is what all this means to client. If I call:

http://kong.example/nifi-api/...

It doesn't work. Browser cant reach the site.

curl -i $PROXY_IP still says 'no route matched with those values'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue should not be related to Kubernetes/Minikube but to the missing route to connect your host (`kong.example`).

To fix it, first, delete the ingress:

```
kubectl delete ingress nifi-api-routing
```

enable ingress on minikube:

```
minikube addons enable ingress
```

get the minikube ip:

```
minikube ip
> 192.168.x.x
```

and use it to add a new line into the file `/etc/hosts` to create the route:

```
192.168.x.x kong.example
```

finally, re-create your ingress with:

```
kubectl apply -f ingressyaml
```

If you search the ingress with `kubectl get ingress`, you should see something like:

```
NAME             CLASS   HOSTS          ADDRESS       PORTS   AGE
nifi-api-routing nginx   kong.example   192.168.x.x   80      5m
```

Now, you can try to browse host with `curl http://kong.example/echo`.

Comment: Thanks. Your inputs helped me made progress. But I still see 3 issues. First, ingress has no ADDRESS assigned. Second, all service calls are fetching same response, some metadata. Third, I still have to make call like 'kong.example:port/nifi-api/....', port must not be needed, isn't?

Comment: I edited my answer because i forgot to mention to enable ingress on minikube. Please revise it to get the IP address. Yes, you don't need to specify the port number with curl.

Comment: I think addons command has to be run before executing yaml for kong-ingress-controller, because KIC depends on nginx ingress. But I am really not sure. Kong documentation is pretty bad, I would say.