# 'host' field in Kubernetes Ingress

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I am pretty novice in Kubernetes.

From the [Kubernetes website](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/), on 'host' field in ingress:

> An optional host. In this example, no host is specified, so the rule
> applies to all inbound HTTP traffic through the IP address specified.
> If a host is provided (for example, foo.bar.com), the rules apply to
> that host.

So if I have host as 'x.y.z', path as '/my-service', then only a call like 'x.y.z/my-service/....' would be directed to the configured backend service.

If host is not set, then any call with /my-service in its url would be send to configured backend.

> x.y.z/my-service/..
>
> a.b.c/my-service/..

Both would be directed to backend.

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Your understanding seems correct, but it seems the best way to resolve this question would be to create a couple of Ingress resources and check the behavior and see if it matches your expectations.

Comment: I actually did it, and it didnt work as I expected. So wanted to clarify.

Comment: If you are seeing behavior that doesn't match your expectations, it might help to include in your question your Ingress resources along with a description of how you tested things (basically, provide a [mcve]).

Comment: I actually have a detailed question asked here..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76573422/configuring-kong-ingress-for-apache-nifi-api-on-minikube

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, your understanding is correct.

`Host` is a optional parameter that indicates to use a certain host. The usage of the `host` argument is also related to the DNS management of that address, so in order to use it you also need to either:

- add the hostname into the DNS record
- edit the `/etc/hosts` file (if you're running your environment locally) with the association `ip hostname`

After you set this up, you match any path that starts with `http://host/path`, e.g. `http://host/path/1`, `http://host/path/2`.

You don't match any path that either modify the host or the path prefix.